# Limit output size of Powershell Background job

Tags: powershell, jobs, throttling

From my local computer, I tried to run a background job on a remote computer through Remote Powershell. Want to know we have some throttling limit to set on the output size of that job to protect the remote computer. E.X. like 10MB?

Comment: The output size? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the limit is reached?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I mean pipeline output size. This is to avoid the the local machine to kick off a job to write too much data.

Comment: @DeanOC, fail the job.